# How to print list with while loop in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, arraylist, while-loop

I'm very new to C# and I'm trying to make my program run through my list with a while loop. I know how to do it with for and for each, and I know these are the best options, but I would very much like to know how I can do it with a while loop.

My list basically looks like this.

```cs
List<Register> list = new List<Register>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);
list.Add(3);
```

I have tried to do this

```cs
int i = 10;
            
while (list.Count >= 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
    i = i - 1;
}
```

But I think I'm doing it all wrong. Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: `while (i>= 0)`

Comment: your condition in while is incorrect and it return you true all time.. 

i = list.count

while(i==0)

Comment: Do you know how to debug your code? If not, than I would highly recommend putting that on top your list to learn. In the debugger you can evaluate at any time what the condition in the while returns, and that way you would see that list.Count returns the number of items in the list each iteration. And because the content of the list stays the same, it will always be true and the loop runs forever.

Comment: @TwistErase, please check if the following answers work for you.

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple

```
var i = 0;
while(i < list.Count)
{
   Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
   ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [while](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-while-statement) loops thought a block as long as the condition is TRUE

```cs
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);
list.Add(3);
list.Add(4);
list.Add(5);

int counter = 0;
while (counter < list.Count)
{
  Console.WriteLine(list[counter]);
  counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
int i = 0;
while (i < numbers.Count)
{
    Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
    i++;
}
```

This will print 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: The first line is not correct.  It should either be `List<string> numbers = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };` or `List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `String.Join` to collect all of your values and print them in a friendly manner.

```cs
Console.WriteLine("["+String.Join(", ", list)+"]");
```

This will print

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

based on the list you have in your question.

But if you want to know how to do it in a while loop, the standard way is:

```cs
int i = 0;
        
while (i < list.Count) {
    Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
    i++;
}
```

You want to start from 0, then work your way up to `i = list.Count - 1` which this will do.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you are trying to loop the list in the reverse order. Therefore, you start with `i` having the maximum value and then you decrease it. This is good so far.

Lists and arrays have an index ranging from 0 to N-1, where N is the number elements in the collection. Therefore, initialize the index like this:

```cs
int i = list.Count - 1;
```

This ensures that the loop will work with any number of elements.

Your loop condition is almost right, except that you are testing the wrong thing. You must test the loop variable `i` (because the `Count` doesn't change and because you are decrementing `i`).

```cs
while (i >= 0)
```

Together:

```cs
int i = list.Count - 1;

while (i >= 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
    i = i - 1;
}
```

---

To loop the list indexes in ascending order, you would write

```cs
int i = 0;

while (i < list.Count)
{
    Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Note that we test `i < list.Count` and not `i <= list.Count`, because the index range is [0 .. list.Count - 1] (with both bounds being inclusive).

---

C# has handy increment and decrement operators `++` and `--`. So, you could write

```cs
i++;
```

or

```cs
i--;
```

instead of `i = i + 1;` or `i = i - 1;`.